# Datediff() overlapping days?

Tags: sql-server, time, sql-server-2012, overlap, datediff

I'm having trouble figuring out how to use the datediff() function for overlapping days.

This is my table and the yellow marked rows i have trouble with .

```
SELECT 
    FOMTID,
    TOMTID,
    DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FOMTID,TOMTID) TIME 
FROM [DATABASE]...
```

[image]

I do **NOT** have a fields like '2001-01-01 23:30' & '2001-01-02 00:00' this would make the date diff function work but i only have the time.

Comment: What are the types of comuns?

Comment: How can the server know that you mean "midnight of next day" and not "midnight of this day," if you don't have the date component? `Datediff` returns negative values when the first argument is less than the second, and that is what you have there. If you don't like this, [add](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186819%28v=sql.120%29.aspx) a whole day to `TOMTID` when calling `datediff` if `FOMTID > TOMTID`.

Comment: FOMTID = varchar(8)
TOMTID = varchar(8)
Time = decimal(8,2) (because i use this field further on in the script)

Comment: if i take one row (18) i would like it to say 32 and not 1408(or -1408)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**[LiveDemo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374452)**

```
SELECT 
  FOMTID,
  TOMTID, 
  [TIME] = IIF(FOMTID <= TOMTID,
              DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FOMTID,TOMTID),
              1440 - DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TOMTID,FOMTID))
FROM your_table;
```

or:

```
SELECT 
  FOMTID,
  TOMTID, 
  [TIME] = IIF(FOMTID <= TOMTID,
                     DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FOMTID,TOMTID),
              1440 + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FOMTID,TOMTID))
FROM your_table;
```

**EDIT:**

**[LiveDemo2](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374466)**

```
WITH cte AS
(
SELECT 
  FOMTID,
  TOMTID, 
  [TIME] = IIF(FOMTID <= TOMTID,
                     DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FOMTID,TOMTID),
              1440 + DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FOMTID,TOMTID))
FROM #tab
)
SELECT FOMTID, TOMTID
   ,[MINUTES] = [TIME]
   ,[TIME]  = CAST([TIME] / 60  + [TIME] % 60 / 100.0 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
   ,[TIME2] = CAST([TIME] / 60  + [TIME] % 60 / 60.0 AS DECIMAL(8,2))
FROM cte
```

Choose how  you want to treat minutes part:

```
[Time]  => 30min => 0.3
[Time2] => 30min => 0.5
```

Comment: i have this in my code to get the hours. could you modify your code to implement this? CAST(CONCAT((DATEDIFF(Minute,T1.FOMTID,T1.TOMTID)/60),'.', (DATEDIFF(Minute,T1.FOMTID,T1.TOMTID)%60)) AS decimal(8,2))

Comment: Thank you.
Im trying to modify my query and looking at yours but what im i doing wrong?
SELECT 
 FOMTID,
 TOMTID,
 CASE WHEN FOMTID <= TOMTID THEN CAST(CONCAT((DATEDIFF(Minute,TOMTID,FOMTID)/60),'.', (DATEDIFF(Minute,TOMTID,FOMTID)%60)) AS decimal(8,2)) END
 FROM [DATABASE]...

Comment: @Nils Forget about concat. I really don't understand why you don't use my code.

Comment: @Nils Here https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/374469. No need for CTE, chagne #tab with [DATABASE]...]

Answer (score 1):

If these are time data types:

```
SELECT FOMTID, TOMTID,
       (CASE WHEN FOMTID <= TOMTID THEN DATEDIFF(MINUTE, FOMTID, TOMTID)
             ELSE 24*60 - DATEDIFF(MINUTE, TOMTID, FOMTID)
        END) AS TIME
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7/3760) is a little SQL Fiddle.